# Yahoo Finance - Historical Intraday Download

Tags: download, yahoo-finance, yfinance

does anybody know why the code below does not bring data after 16:55hr? The market actually closes at 18:00 in Brazil. This happens for all tickers ending in ".SA" in Yahoo Finance.

```
      import yfinance as yf

      data = yf.download("PETR4.SA", group_by="Ticker", period='1mo', interval='5m',prepost = True)
      data['ticker'] = "PETR4.SA"
      data
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of an interesting question. I checked the code. I've been working with several providers, including Yahoo Finance, and I believe it could be more a "pre definition" on the API than a programming/requisition mistake.

As the stock negotiations at B3 normally take place until 17:00 pm (-3 UTC, São Paulo Timezone), the function is returning the last valid computed value i.e. 16:55 pm.

As an exercise I tried to change the time in-between the data from "5m" to "2m" and I spotted the last value at 16:58 pm (same logic).  I don't know how to bypass that.
It appears to be the way it works.